# counting how often a given word occurs in a given file, ignoring case using R

Tags: r

for example :

```
currency <- grepl ("currencry" , strsplit("euro currency is a convertible currency"," "), ignore.case=TRUE)
```

but it returns only TRUE how can I count how many times the word currency is appeared in this sentence using this grepl function ?

Sorry but I am a beginner . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strsplit` returns a list (so that you can input a vector of character). You need to "unlist" it first:

```
currency <- grepl ("currency" , unlist(strsplit("euro currency is a convertible currency"," ")), ignore.case=TRUE)
currency
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
sum(currency)
[1] 2
```

Answer (score 5):

No need to use `regular expression` here:

```
 sum(scan(text="euro currency is a convertible currency",
          what="character") == "currency")
 ## 2
```

In case you want to ignore case -)

```
 sum(scan(text=tolower("euro curreNcy is a convertible currencY"),
          what="character") == "currency")
```

Comment: +1 but you don't have the ability to ignore case with this approach (thought that may be unnecessary)

Comment: I'd give you another +1. Pragmatic way of overcoming that. Nice one!

Comment: thank you guys!!!! and you know if there is any possibility to count how many different words there are in a text noting the existence of punctuation characters?

Comment: @AnastaciaDed It is better to try on your own and ask a new question if you don't have a solution. better than asking this as a comment. That's said , you should clean your text ( remove punctuation ) and use `unique` for example to remove duplicated words. Better, to use some text mining package see `tm package` for example...

Answer (score 3):

I would use `gregexpr` as follows:

```
lapply(gregexpr("currency", 
                "euro currency is a convertible currency", 
                ignore.case=TRUE), 
       length)
# [[1]]
# [1] 2
```

(And I would make sure that you are spelling your search pattern correctly).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `qdap` package:

```
library(qdap)

termco("euro currency is a convertible currency",, "currency")

##   all word.count  currency
## 1 all          6 2(33.33%)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `table`

```
> s <- strsplit("euro currency is a convertible currency", " ")[[1]]
> tab <-table(s)
> tab["currency"]
# currency 
#        2
```

This is nice is you need to store the table of all words.  You can look up any word with `tab["word"]` For example

```
> tab["convertible"]
# convertible
#           1
```